# increment operator ++i does not cause an error in python

Tags: python, operators, increment

Since the increment operator ++ is not supported in python, why doesn't it cause an error when  prefixing a variable. Example:

```
i = 3
++i
```

prints 3 on the interactive console. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look - it's just a sign:

```
>>> i = 3
>>> +i
3
>>> ++i
3
>>> +++i
3
>>> -i
-3
>>> --i
3
>>> ---i
-3
```

Comment: Just figured it out a few secs ago. Thanks and answer accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Python treats `++i` as `+(+i)`, that would compile fine, and print the same value as of `i`.